# Flutter MethodChannel from iOS to Native not working

Tags: ios, flutter, native, flutter-method-channel

I have a Flutter project trying to establish two-way communication between Flutter and iOS Native. So far it's working perfectly from *Flutter* to *iOS*, but the other way around it's silent. When I call the method from iOS, nothing happens. No message, no errors, no nothing.

I create the **MethodChannel** on *iOS* like this:

```
let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(
    name: "paymentview",
    binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger
)

   channel.setMethodCallHandler({
       (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in
       if (call.method == "initialize") {

       } else if(call.method == "authorize") {

        }
   })
```

And like this on the *Flutter* side:

```
_channel = new MethodChannel('paymentview');
_channel.setMethodCallHandler(methodCallHandler);

Future<dynamic> methodCallHandler(MethodCall methodCall) async {
    switch (methodCall.method) {
      case 'authorized':
        print("authorized");
        return null;
      default:
        throw PlatformException(code: 'Not implemented', message: 'Not implemented');
    }
  }
```

On *Flutter* I invoke a method like this:

```
_channel.invokeMethod('authorize');
```

And that works fine. The call is received in iOS. But on the iOS side I call a method like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.channel.invokeMethod("authorized", arguments: nil)
        }
```

And nothing happens on the *Flutter* side. No message, no error, no nothnig. I've tried numerous variants, with creating multiple channels (one each way), dynamic channel ids, and so on, but it's silent on the *Flutter* side. Any ideas?

Edit: I've debugged this from the iOS side, and it does work. I get the return value from my Dart code. However, when I debug the Dart code, no breakpoints are hit. If I try to modify some state in Dart, nothing happens...

Edit2: It seems to work when run from XCode, using the runner project, but not when running the Flutter project from Android Studio..

Comment: Im getting a similar issue, did you fixed it?

Comment: Hey. I'm very sorry for this "solution", but it suddenly started working after a few reboots and Android Studio cache invalidation, etc. I have no good explanation :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this suddenly started working without any code changes. I rebooted my mac a few times, refreshed Android Studio, etc. And suddenly it worked.

Comment: same thing done with me

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing similar issues and using custom iOS-side storyboard or root view controller: make sure that FlutterViewController remains root VC and you make further native iOS navigation without replacing it.

In my similar issue, the reason of described behaviour itself was definitely in changing root view controller from FlutterViewController to my custom iOS UIViewController (reason - plugin had a reference to native SDK which used its own storyboard).

UPD: there is an issue which describes possible reasons of merely expected behaviour: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52456